# Want a popup in asp.net project that on clicking the continue button continues the execution from where it was left

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've a .aspx page designed to appear as a popup and I want to call that page from another .aspx page
On clicking continue button on the popup page it should continue from where the popup was redirected means it should continue from where it was left

Answer (score 0):

The term "continue" is rather confusing.

I would assume say, that you may want to have  button on a page (first page).

On that page, you want to click a button, popup (display) that 2nd page - perhaps get some user input.

Now, if the user hits cancel, then say the server side code would not run, but if they hit ok, then the code would run.

In other words, it not really that you are to "continue" - and continue to where? IN code, in the page, return to the previosu page? So I find the term "continue" here is less then ideal.

If you suggesting (or wanting) that you can do this in code behind such as run soem code, pop dialog, wait, and then have that code continue? No, web land don't work that way and you can't do that.

You could certainly however with code behind pop a dialog (client browser side), and if they hit cancel, then nothing happens, and if they hit say "ok", then another sub or routine in that page as a result could run.

So in other words based on the user input, they would continue about their required business, but the code behind would not for example "wait".

However, as we all know, any standard button on a page can call both client side code, and server side code for the one button. And the client side code can for example toss up a "confirm" or even a nice looking dialog, and based on "ok" or say some cancel button you would thus run (or not run) the actions of the button.

So, you might say drop in a button to delete the record you are viewing. but, quite easy to hit that delete button so you also might and some kind of "dialog" or popup page - and that popup could be another aspx page if you want. And again based on user input, you would then optional run the button (server) side code. In fact, this would produce the same effect as say a windows confirmation dialog. The only difference is that confirm dialog would pop before the code behind starts, and thus is not really a "continue" process as much as a dialog that says yes, go ahead and do what I want, or no don't do that.

So, expand on what you mean by "continue" and also expand on what that 2nd dialog needs to do? Is it data input, or some type of confirm type of dialog?

So such routines? You would have two routines. The first routine could do some things - and then popup a confirm dialog. And upon a yes/no, then a 2nd routine that follows can be used. But no, you can't halt in the middle of one routine with server side code.